# Problem Opening Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient)

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am developing an application that contains a small SQL Server database File.

On my machine, it works fine. I am using Microsoft Visual C# Express 2010.

I have sent my project to a colleague. He is using the same software. And he has placed the database file in the same place (`c:\folder\db.mdf`). However, he gets the following error when trying to open the connection:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled
>   Message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
>   found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
>   and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
>   Server/Instance Specified)

How can I help my colleague get connected? He is on the other side of the country.

Comment: Does your colleague have SQL Server Express (same version or newer) installed? What does your connection string look like (to make the connection to the database)??

Comment: The error messages says that the SQL server could not be found (on his machine). You may need to edit the connection string.

Comment: The connection string is: @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\betfairData\db.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";  I do not know whether or not the user has Visual SQL Express installed, but he assures me that the datbase file is in the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to copy a database from one machine to another - the way I normally do it is to use SQL Server management studio to do a backup on the "from" and then to do a restore on the "to".

For more information, check out questions/answers like:

- [Copy SQL Server Express Database to Another Computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612149/copy-sql-server-express-database-to-another-computer)
- [SQL Server 2005: how to copy database from one server to another (manually/programmatically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389179/sql-server-2005-how-to-copy-database-from-one-server-to-another-manually-progra)
- [Easiest way to copy an entire SQL server Database from a server to local SQL Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243583/easiest-way-to-copy-an-entire-sql-server-database-from-a-server-to-local-sql-expr)
- [Programmatically detach SQL Server database to copy mdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757036/programmatically-detach-sql-server-database-to-copy-mdf-file)